# On GlassFish got max pool size exception because of cannot close connection created from DataSource

Tags: java, glassfish, connection-pooling

I got max pool size exception on GlassFish when open connection from DataSource although open and close function coupled manually. I google all around but there is no answer! 
Could anyone help me?

My code snippet as following: (my setting initial connection pool: 8, max-pool-size: 32, Idle Timeout: 300s, max-wait-time: 60s)
got exception max pool size when call work() function

```
public class BP{

    @Resource(name="BP", type = javax.sql.DataSource.class)

    private DataSource ds;



    public void work(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            doSomething();
        }
    }
    public void doSomething(){
        java.sql.Connection conn = null;        
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;        
        try{
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            cs = conn.prepareCall("{ call get_bank(?,?) }");
            cs.setString(1, "test");
            cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);         
            cs.execute();
            rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(2);/

            // do something
            //...       
        } catch (Exception e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if (rs != null) {
              try {
                rs.close();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }

            if (cs != null) {
              try {
                cs.close();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }

            if (conn != null) {
              try {
                conn.close();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections.
```

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` should show you more detail than the error occurring when you call work().  it is probably in your call `ds.getConnection()`. Your code doesn't show how you initialise `ds`, so the issue may be here.

Comment: Thanks Simo,  Output: "Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections". ds variable is referenced from pool by "@Resource(name="BP", type = javax.sql.DataSource.class)"

Comment: I see the number of being used connections on monitoring admin webpage that  32 connections exhausted. Perhaps Glassfish does not  actually release connection although called to connnection.close() function!

Answer (score 0):

The last block of your finally statement is probably your issue.

You are doing `.close()` on `connection` not on `conn`.  Meaning you are referencing the wrong object.

```
if (conn != null) {
      try {
            connection.close();   <---- should be conn.close()
      } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake in my example, so I corrected the example source! But the problem is still there. Could you find out any solution? thanks

Comment: @GoldenMan with what you have provided, i cannot see any further issues.  Can you debug the doSomething() one by one?

Comment: Hi Simo, thanks for support. If your debug one line by one line, perhaps the problem does not appear. The issue (max pool size exception) would appear if you run work() function without mark any break-point in source.